# Fill model properties in cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor, model

When I declare a model in cshtml with the code below,

```
@model Mymodel;
```

then all properties are empty
I would like to display the id and I tried to call a property with: `@Model.id` but the result is 0

Can I fill it in .cshtml file or into controller?

Comment: Did you read following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller

Answer (score 0):

`@model HRM.Core.DTO.YourModel   <-- the address of your model @{ Layout = null; }`

and where you call id just reference this below code.[code attach here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkcXS.png)

Comment: Please enter all code as properly formatted text, not as images.

Answer (score 0):

If you just declare `@model Mymodel` in your view, It means this view receives `Mymodel` model and use this model to pass data between view and controller.

Now if you want your view to receive a model with value, you need to pass the value to this model and return it to your view.

For example, If you use Test action to render this view,

```
public IActionResult Test()
        {
            Mymodel mymodel = new Mymodel();

            //put the value which you wanna display to this model from db or something else
            //..........

            //return this model to the view
            return View(mymodel);
        }
```

I recommend you to check this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to learn more details.